# Difference between sound and audio nodes in RPi 3 device tree?

Tags: raspbian-stretch, alsa, device-tree

I looked a bit into the device tree of Raspbian 9 on Raspberry Pi 3, using:

```
dtc -I fs /proc/device-tree > myrpi-dev-tree.txt 2>&1
```

I've noticed there is a node called `audio`:

```
audio {
        brcm,pwm-channels = <0x8>;
        compatible = "brcm,bcm2835-audio";
        status = "okay";
        phandle = <0x25>;
        pinctrl-0 = <0x1c>;
        pinctrl-names = "default";
};
```

... which apparently handles the default audio on the Raspberry Pi 3 - I guess, that would be the card shown as "bcm2835 ALSA":

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA], device 0: bcm2835 ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA]
  Subdevices: 7/7
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
  Subdevice #2: subdevice #2
  Subdevice #3: subdevice #3
  Subdevice #4: subdevice #4
  Subdevice #5: subdevice #5
  Subdevice #6: subdevice #6
card 0: ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA], device 1: bcm2835 ALSA [bcm2835 IEC958/HDMI]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

However, there is also a `sound` node:

```
sound {
        status = "disabled";
        phandle = <0x72>;
};
```

... which is disabled, with not much in it.

As far as I can tell from what I've read on the net, nodes are (in principle) arbitrarily named in a device tree.

However, for me, `sound` and `audio` (just as plain English words) are more or less synonyms in context of software.

So, why are there two device nodes for sound/audio? Why didn't the developers simply use just one (and call it either `sound` or `audio`)? Is it a convention (of either Linux device tree - or of Raspberry Pi systems) - or is there another meaning/intent behind usage of two nodes thus named?

Comment: According to `/boot/overlays/README` there is no overlay `sound` available. Maybe you have found an only internal node in the device tree?

Comment: Many thanks @Ingo - well, that is what I observe after boot; and then I can also see [hifiberry-dacplus-overlay.dts](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/blob/rpi-4.14.y/arch/arm/boot/dts/overlays/hifiberry-dacplus-overlay.dts) uses `target = <&sound>;` to overlay that node, so it must have some sort of a meaning ?!

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not familiar with the internals of device trees. My "cookbook" is that `/boot/overlays/README` and there is a some sections for `hifiberry` including `hifiberry-dacplus`.